# PNG bytearray to bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bitmap

I have a BLOB(bytearray) in my local sqlite. I'd like to print the image but because it's PNG. transparent areas looks black. In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X99wI.jpg) image I have a white icon, not with black background.

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByte, 0, imageByte.size)
```

I just want to image with transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue writing the byte PNG in writing the database using the following code below.

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArray)
```